# WebRTC, how to gather a full set of candidates without ice trickle?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to make a video call between two pc's, and I don't want to use ice trickle, sometimes I can make the video call, other times(I don't know why) I can't gather all the ice candidates, the iceGatheringState stays in gathering state and never goes to complete.

I already tried to use the event onicecandidate and wait for the null candidate.
Now I'm using onIceGatheringStateChange.

```
pc=new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
pc.onicegatheringstatechange=function(){
  if(pc.iceGatheringState=='complete'){
    send_to_target(pc.localDescription);
  }
}   
localStream.getTracks().forEach(track=>pc.addTrack(track,localStream));
pc.createOffer().then(function(sessionDescription){
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
})
```

I'm testing this in two laptops with chrome, and I want that iceGatheringState goes to complete state or know another way/condition to gather the ice candidates in order to send the sessionDescription to target without the use of ice trickle.

Thanks.

Comment: Use lowercase: `pc.onicegatheringstatechange`.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, the problem is the same, I want to know a way to gather the ice candidates before send the session description. My ideia now is to get "one of each expected type of candidates" as I see in [issue 7844](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7844)

Comment: I give up, now I'm using Ice Trickle and works fine but I still don't understand why I can't get pc.iceGatheringState=='complete' without Ice Trickle.

Comment: That's an interesting question, if end-of-candidates is transmitted in the offer. What browsers have you tried this in?

Comment: I tried only Chrome, in one laptop everything was fine, in the other after setLocalDescription the iceGatheringState was 'gathering' and don't change to 'complete', and also I did not receive the candidate null, now with ice trickle I receive the null candidate and the gathering state goes to 'complete', the only difference I can point Is that one laptop has windows 7 and the other windows 10

Comment: [Wfm](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/fbphw3xn/). Does the problem laptop have virtual machines, VPN (even if you're not using it) or some secondary network card? I've seen ICE take up to 20 seconds to complete on some browsers in rare circumstances depending on the system.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are two ways to determine when the "ICE candidate gathering" / "ICE Trickle" is complete.

1. You can determine that ICE candidate gathering is complete by watching for icegatheringstatechange events and checking for the value of iceGatheringState to be equal to "complete".

[Code example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/icegatheringstatechange_event)

```
let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
pc.onicegatheringstatechange = ev => {
  let connection = ev.target;

  switch(connection.iceGatheringState) {
    case "gathering":
      /* collection of candidates has begun */
      break;
    case "complete":
      /* collection of candidates is finished */
      break;
  }
}
```

2. You can also have your handler for the icecandidate event look to see if its candidate property is equal to "null".

[Code example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate)

```
let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    /* Code for each candidate */
    /* Send the candidate to the remote peer */
  } else {
    /* All ICE candidates have been sent */
  }
}
```

Helpful links for WebRTC:

- [Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebRTC)
- [Simple Data Channel Code Example on GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/tree/master/s/webrtc-simple-datachannel)
- [*WebRTC For The Curious*](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/)